# Applying translate and scale animations sequentially

Tags: android, animation, coordinates, transform, tween

I'm trying to create some kind of gallery view for my game's level select menu. There are three items placed horizontally and two buttons: left and right. When I press the right button those three items should all move to left, and when there's a left button click - the items move to right. I've found a problem using a transform animations `android:fillAfter` atribute: if it's `true` and I click a button for the first time the items move where they must and stay there as expected. But on the second click they start moving from their initial position, means their actual coordinates don't change after the first transformation. Am I missing something? How can I achieve that goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`android:fillAfter` doesn't change the attributes of the view.  It just means they draw in place once the animation is done, but their physical attributes are the same.  Your translate animation probably is animating relative to where they are physically located.  Also note, the views aren't actually in the location that you've moved them which means if the user touches them, the touch won't register.  They will register if the user touches where they used to be though.

What you need to do in this case is animate them from the location they're currently viewed at to the location you want them to be.

Possible solution:

From left to right:

```
TranslateAnimation (Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1.0, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0);
```

From right to left:

```
TranslateAnimation (Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1.0, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0);
```

In this case, I'm animating from left to right from 0% to 100% relative to the parent.  With the `fillAfter` enabled, the View will (visibly) stay.  After that, I'm animating from right to left from 100% to 0% relative to the parent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's what I'm actually doing. Everytime I apply a 100% left offset to an item, but everytime it just moves from its initial position. Is there a way to redefine a view's coordinates after the animation finishes?

Comment: With pre-Honeycomb animations, I don't think there's a way to do it without changing the properties yourself.  You may need a custom view that reads it's current location `onAnimationEnd`, changes it's location, then forces a `layout` pass.

Comment: @Egor: I'm probably stating the obvious here, but it's the only other thing that's come to mind.  You may also want to try to apply the `fillBefore` attribute to true as well.  It's true by default, but if you're setting it to false (as well as `fillEnabled` to true), then the initial attributes of the animation won't be applied before the animation.